# Tiny MCE - Shows only basic set up?

Tags: javascript, php

I have downloaded the "full set" version of Tiny MCE. I place it in my php form just as instructed. But I only get the barebones basic set. I have all the plugins in the Plug in folder???  I use the following code as instructed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea"
        });
    </script>
```

It works fine BUT I can't get the plugins and advanced features to show? See screen shot.
[image: screen shot b=of baritones setup]

How do I config to have all of the plug-ins and features show?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For TinyMCE 3.x, this configuration will show full featured Editor,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Skin options
        skin : "o2k7",
        skin_variant : "silver",

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/example.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
                username : "Some User",
                staffid : "991234"
        }
});
</script>
```

Official link: [here](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add few config options like theme_advanced_buttons1 theme_advanced_buttons2 theme_advanced_buttons3

theme_advanced_buttons1  will show buttons on first line
theme_advanced_buttons2  will show buttons on second line
theme_advanced_buttons3  will show buttons on third line

You can find various [config options from here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration)